# Justify Arabic Rich Text To Align Both Right And Left Sides In Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to justify both ends of my book like application for arabic Quran, however only the right side is justified, in short I want to evenly space the words for each line.

Is it possible to do it as shown in the photo.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcZqe.jpg) [What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPva.jpg)

```
  List<TextSpan> preparePageVerses(int pageNum) {
    String rawVerses = versesDataBase[pageNum];

    List<String> verses = rawVerses.split('\n');
    List<TextSpan> verseSpans = [];

    for (String verse in verses) {
      List<String> words = verse.split(' ');

      List<TextSpan> wordSpans = [];

      bool isDarkMode = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;

      for (String word in words) {
        wordSpans.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: '$word ',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
              fontFamily: word.contains('\uFD3F') && word.contains('\uFD3E')
                  ? 'QuranSurahBracketsFont'
                  : 'QuranVerseFont',
            ),
            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                 print(word);
              },
          ),
        );
      }

      // Add a newline character at the end of each line
      wordSpans.add(TextSpan(text: '\n'));

      verseSpans.addAll(wordSpans);
    }

    return verseSpans;
  }
```

It seems a single line of text works perfectly fine, but with my design it's a bit complicated.

Edit : with TextAlign.justify, I get only the right-hand side justified
result : [TextAlign.justify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErvOT.jpg)

```
   RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      text: TextSpan(
        children: preparePageVerses(2),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Does `textAlign: TextAlign.justify` solve your issue? It should be placed in your `RichText` widget (which I presume you're using to render your TextSpan) like so `RichText(text:..., textAlign: TextAlign.justify)`

Comment: @TrueKing Thank you for the advice, you are correct I am using RichText and TextSpan, I have tried your suggestion but only the right-hand side is justified

        RichText(          
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          text: TextSpan(
            children: preparePageVerses(2),
          ),
        ),